# uniq command - how to get delimiter option and search on the basis of column?

Tags: sorting, command, uniq

Below is sorted (on the basis of column one )tab delineated file named file.txt

```
barbie  325 social activist
david   214 IT professional
david   457 mathematician
david   458 biologist
john    85  engineer
john    98  doctor
peter   100 statistician
```

i want run uniq command on the basis of column one using options (-t and -k in case of sort commands)

```
uniq -d (-t$'\t' -k1,1) file.txt [this is incorrect syntax in bracket , but i want to run it in similar way]
```

Well this would be quite easy but i am unable to find my way.

so that i can get output as :

```
david   214 IT professional
john    85  engineer
```

Help me , Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where does "214 IT professional" come from?  (And why is Engineer uppercase, while all the misspelled ones are lowercase?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian `uniq` used to have this option, but it was removed for compatibility reasons.  You can create your own AWK or Perl script easily.  This prints only the lines with the first occurrence of the first field:

```
awk -F '\t' '!x[$1]++' file.txt
```

`x[$1]` is an associative array on the contents of the first field (`$1`); it gets incremented for each line, but it is also the as the condition which specifies whether or not the current line should be printed; with the negation, it is true only if this field value has not been encountered before.  (Reminder: the general form of an AWK script is zero or more of `condition { action }` and both parts are optional; if `{action}` is missing, the default action is to print the current line. [If the condition is missing, the action is taken unconditionally.])